# Sum of n terms of (n - k)^a

Tags: sequences-and-series

What would be the summation of n-2 terms for this series. Here x = (n-1) and a is a constant
$$\sum_{k=1}^x (n-k)^a$$

Note: This is not any homework problem and I have created this equation on my own and trying to find a simplified equation for the same.

In simple terms can we simplify and write a generic equation for:
$$2^a+3^a+4^a+...+(n-1)^a$$

Comment: Why would you use $x$ at all? It’s a symbol you would never use for a restriction to the integers, which is necessary for the summation to make sense.

Comment: Also the answer follows trivially from: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula It probably isn’t as nice as you’d like, but it’s the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

$b = -k$ 
$$(n + b)^a = \sum_{m=0}^a\left(\binom{a}{m} n^{a-m}b^m\right)$$
So we just put another sommation around this one
$$\sum_{p=0}^x\left(\sum_{m=0}^a\left(\binom{a}{m} n^{a-m}b^m\right)\right) = $$
$$\sum_{p=0}^x\left(\sum_{m=0}^a\left(\binom{a}{m} n^{a-m}(-k)^m\right)\right) =$$
$$(x+1)\left(\sum_{m=0}^a\left(\binom{a}{m}n^{a-m}(-k)^m\right)\right)$$
Which results in the answer

EDT: I also explained some other ways in the comments of this answer, that should help you out too.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time but it didn't simplify the equation. You are just adding another sigma to the existing binomial theorem and it didn't reduce the complexity if am not wrong

Comment: This is simpler to me tho, I hate $(a + b)^x$ :( but then you should specify what you mean by simpler: you want to remove the sigma? That's easy! Just create a sequence $p( q)= p(q-1) + (n-q)a$, or, if you don't really care about precision, use the integral of $f(q) =(n-k)^q$ $D_f = [0, x]$

Comment: Typo in the old comment in the $f(q)$ but you get the idea. Also you could use $\floor{(f(q))}$ which integral actually is correct

Comment: Also, in that case, this may come in handy https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula

Comment: Thanks for the information about Faulhaber's formula